# How to reference another style class for complex selectors with material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

With something like `styled-components` [you were able to reference the generated classes of other components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) like so:

```
const Header = styled.header`
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
`

const CloseButton = styled.button`
   padding: 0;
   border-width: 0;

   &:before {
     content: "x";
   }

   ${Header} > & {
     margin-left: auto;
   }
`
```

Material-UI has both the `styled` function that is patterned on this and the `makeStyles` function (which is in some ways superior), yet I cannot figure out how to achieve a similar effect here and to combine class selectors in more complex ways. The documentation is very sparse on the topic, they just say that you can used `styled` as a mostly drop in replacement but then the actual api for it is with an object where this sort of thing is not possible.

So how do you do more complex selectors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MUI uses CSS-in-JS

Use `$ruleName` to [reference a local rule name](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) within the same `makeStyles` style sheet.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  Header: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    display: "flex"
  },
  CloseButton: {
    padding: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,

    "&:before": {
      content: "'x'"
    },

    "$Header > &": { // <-- pay attention to usage of $
      marginLeft: "auto"
    }
  }
});
```

Below is what your `CSS` would look like:

[image]

Comment: aha, thanks, is there a way to reference classes from other style sheets?

Comment: I have the same question that can we reference to the parent component's style which pass the classes props to child component?